# How to obtain the "handle to the logical device" HDEV belonging to the GDI engine as passed to DrvEnablePDEV?

Tags: winapi, gdi, printers, wdk

I am interested in being able to call `DrvEnablePDEV` for an arbitrary printer so I can examine the device information. To do this I need (on top of a lot of other things) the `HDEV` which is described in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556211(v=vs.85).aspx) as

> GDI-supplied handle to the device. This handle must be used as input to some GDI callbacks, such as EngGetDriverName.

Is it possible for me to obtain this handle used by the engine somehow? Or could I substitute it for some other handle? (although I'm guessing that would be risky at best)

Comment: You realize that DrvEnablePDEV is a function provided by printer drivers for *Windows* to call?  (How are you even getting a pointer to it?)

Comment: Yes I know. Pointer to what? I am getting the function just from the printer driver dll. Getting the function is not a problem at all. (It's an exported function, that's how the engine gets it)

Comment: Oh, right, printer drivers get loaded into the application's address space so I guess you can just call GetProcAddress.  Making such a call is always going to be dangerous, though, because the printer driver won't be expecting it.  Given that caveat, the most obvious way to capture the handle is to hook the `DrvEnablePDEV` function.  (Although I suppose if you're doing that you might as well simply capture the device information in the hook.)

Comment: I don't think you understand, I am asking how to get the engine's hdev for a different printer. I can't rely on the engine calling the driver, I'm the one that's doing that. But thank you for the idea.

Comment: OK.  If nobody else has any better ideas, you can presumably force the engine to call the driver by calling the appropriate API functions.  I expect CreateDC() would do it.

Comment: That's a good idea, although I still need to hook the target dll, which I think will be very unpleasant for drivers. On top of that there's the problem of me passing mysterious GDI handles around when I don't know whether it's safe to do so or not. Will have to keep looking into it. Thanks for your help Harry, let me know if you have any other ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there's a good way to fake out the DLLs for the print driver. There are values in the registry under the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Environments` that point to the binary names. By copying my own driver into the print driver v3 directory and mocking the names in the registry I can get the functions and all their arguments as they come through and corresponding to the right driver. So then I can just call `CreateDC` or something on the print driver to get access to the driver's entry points.

Restarting the print spooler service is necessary for the registry changes to take effect.

Thanks to Harry Johnston for the idea of hooking the driver DLL, which got me on a good track.